# Is it possible to get a lace sensor tone without the lace sensor pickups on a Fender standard strat?

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups

Just out of curiosity. Without time to experiment it, I wonder if it is possible to make a Fender standard stratocaster sound like a strat with lace sensor pickups on it?

Comment: Put those on it if you are looking for that. This question is most likely to subjective to answer at all.

Comment: Yeah I'm a little confused by this question. What's the downside to actual Lace Sensor pickups that makes you not want to just use them to get their tone?

Comment: Thanks. We can always approach a question hypothetically :). An extreme example would be: People wonder what it is like for one to die; but this does not require one to die in order to get an answer, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently have lace sensors that I put into my strat about 6 months ago, the classic blue-silver-red combo that many 90's Stratocaster deluxe's had. So trust me when I say that there is absolutely nothing you can do to make ordinary pickups sound like lace sensors. I tried pickup height, string action, string tension/bridge adjustment, equalisation...anything I could to sound more like I had lace sensors and nothing works. Nothing works because lace sensor pickups sound the way they do because of their compressed electromagnetic field which adds dynamics and tones that can't be obtained by any other pickups! Your best bet is to just buy some.

[image]

Comment: Thks it is useful information